# Updating filtered listview with a custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, filter

I'm creating a music player. This class among other things is suppose to add new songs to the playlist.
A new window pops up with available songs and the checked songs get added. Songs can be filtered and the selected rows are to change the color when the checkbox is checked. The filtering works and everything is being added the way it's suppose to but...

The problem is that when I check a song/some songs and then click on the search filter and the soft keyboard pops up the color of the selected rows changes to the default color, (the the song is still checked and can be added to the Playlist). When songs are checked and I hide the keyboard the same thing happens.

The other issue is that when the list gets filtered the color of the row previously selected goes away as well when the search box is cleared, the songs remain schecked though.

And I don't understand how and why that happens and therefore how to fix this. 
Anyone has any ideas, please?

I think I don't understand how updating after filtering  works and what notifyDataSetChanged() does exactly.

Here's the adapter code :

```
public class MyTrackAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File> 
{
    private final Activity context;   
    private ArrayList<File> album, temp;   
    private ArrayList<File> piosenki;

    public MyTrackAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<File> album) 
    {   
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_traki, album);   

        this.context = context;   
        this.temp = new ArrayList<File>(album);
        this.album = album;   
        this.piosenki=new ArrayList<File>();        
    } 

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
    {   
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();   
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_traki, null,true);   
        final CheckBox cb_plus = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        final int position1=position;

        final TextView txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);   

        if(position1 %2 == 1) rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bbcolor);
        else rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bpcolor);

        txt.setText(album.get(position1).getName().toString().replace(".mp3",""));   

        cb_plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if (cb_plus.isChecked())
                {
                    cb_plus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x2);       
                    txt.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bdcolor));

                    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.acolor);
                    piosenki.add(album.get(position1));
                }
                else 
                {
                    cb_plus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus);
                    txt.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gcolor));

                    if(position1 %2 == 1) rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bbcolor);
                    else rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bpcolor);
                    piosenki.remove(album.get(position1));
                }
            }
        }); 

        return rowView;        
    } 

    public void showTost(String s)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getpiosenki()
    {   
        return piosenki;
    }

    public Filter getFilter()
    {           
        return filtr;
    }

    private Filter filtr = new Filter()
    {   
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence s)
        {   
            FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<File> f = new ArrayList<File>();

            if(s==null || s.length()==0) f.addAll(temp);                            
            else
            {   
                String ss=s.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(File ff : temp) if(ff.getName().replace(".mp3", "").toLowerCase().contains(ss)) f.add(ff);                                  
            }

            r.values=f;
            r.count=f.size();

            return r;           
        } 

        protected void publishResults(CharSequence s, FilterResults r)
        {   
            album.clear();
            album.addAll((ArrayList)r.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        } 
    };
}
```

And the Playlist class :

```
public class Playlist extends Activity implements TextWatcher
{
    int where;
    long pos;
    String pllist;
    ArrayList<String> lstp, lsts;
    ArrayList<Long> lsti;
    ArrayList<Integer> lstx;
    DBHandler db;

    private TextView txt1, txt2;
    ImageView pic;
    private ListView lv_traki;

    ListView lv_traki2add;
    PopupWindow pw;
    View popupv;
    TextView etext;
    MyTrackAdapter tadapter;
    ImageView add2list;
    ArrayList <File> piosenki, toadd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());    

        Intent tnt = getIntent();
        Bundle bn = tnt.getExtras();

        lstp = (ArrayList) bn.getParcelableArrayList("path");
        lsts = (ArrayList) bn.getParcelableArrayList("song"); 
        lsti = (ArrayList) bn.getParcelableArrayList("indx");
        lstx = (ArrayList) bn.getParcelableArrayList("pause"); 
        pos = bn.getLong("pos", 0);
        where = bn.getInt("skad", 0);
        pllist = bn.getString("album");

        piosenki = (ArrayList) bn.getParcelableArrayList("full"); 

        setData(0, lstp.size());    

        songlist(); 

        lv_traki.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int i, long l)
            {

                Intent it;          
                lstp.clear();
                                lsti.clear();
                                lsts.clear();
                                lstx.clear();

                db.gett1path(pos, lstp);
                db.gett1song(pos, lsts);
                db.gett1pause(pos, lstx);
                db.gett1id(pos, lsti); 

                it=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);       
                it.putExtra("path", lstp).putExtra("nazwa", lsts).putExtra("pause", lstx).putExtra("pos",i).putExtra("skad",4);
                startActivity(it);

            }                       
        });

        if(where==5) lv_traki.performItemClick(lv_traki.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, lv_traki.getAdapter().getItemId(0));

        add2list = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_addtoplay);
        toadd = new ArrayList<File>();

        add2list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {           
                popupv = ((LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.popup_addtolist, null);
                ImageView btn01 = (ImageView) popupv.findViewById(R.id.btn_addtoplay);
                FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
                etext = (EditText) popupv.findViewById(R.id.etext);
                etext.addTextChangedListener(Playlist.this); 

                lv_traki2add = (ListView) popupv.findViewById(R.id.lst_traki2add);
                tadapter = new MyTrackAdapter(Playlist.this, piosenki);
                lv_traki2add.setAdapter(tadapter);

                toadd=tadapter.getpiosenki();

                btn01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(View view) 
                    {
                        if(toadd.size()>0)  
                    {   
                        for (File addt1 : toadd) 
                            {
                                db.addt1(pos, addt1);                               
                            }

                            lstp.clear();
                            lsts.clear();
                            lstx.clear();
                            lsti.clear();

                            db.gett1path(pos, lstp);
                            db.gett1song(pos, lsts);
                            db.gett1pause(pos, lstx);
                            db.gett1id(pos, lsti);
                            lv_traki.setAdapter(null);

                            setData(0, lstp.size());    

                            MyPlaylistAdapter adapter=new MyPlaylistAdapter(Playlist.this, lsts, lstp, lsti, lstx, pos, pllist, lv_traki, txt2);   
                            lv_traki.setAdapter(adapter);   

                            for(int x=0; x<lv_traki2add.getChildCount(); x++)
                            {                           
                                CheckBox cb = lv_traki2add.getChildAt(x).findViewById(R.id.add);                                                
                                cb.setChecked(false);                                    
                            }

                        pw.dismiss();
                        showTost("Songs Added");
                    }               
                    else pw.dismiss();                                                                                     
                    }
                });

                pw = new PopupWindow(popupv, -1, -1, true);
                pw.showAtLocation(fl, 17, 0, 0);
            }
        });

    } 

    private void songlist()
    {
        lv_traki = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_traki);

        MyPlaylistAdapter adapter=new MyPlaylistAdapter(this, lsts, lstp, lsti, lstx, pos, pllist, lv_traki, txt2);   
        lv_traki.setAdapter(adapter);   
    }

    public void setData(int z, int size)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
        MediaMetadataRetriever tmp = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
        mmr.setDataSource(lstp.get(z));

        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_bg);

        int tmax = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
        {
            tmp.setDataSource(lstp.get(i));
            tmax+=Integer.parseInt(tmp.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)); 
            tmax+=lstx.get(i)*1000;
        }

            txt1.setText(pllist);

            if (size>1) txt2.setText(size+" songs;   "+mili_t(tmax)); 
            else txt2.setText("1 song;   "+mili_t(tmax)); 

        Bitmap bm; 
        Drawable d;

        byte [] img = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

        if(img!=null)
        {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length); 
            d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm); 
            pic.setBackground(d);
        }
        else
        {
            pic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_image);
            pic.getLayoutParams().height = 400;
            pic.getLayoutParams().width = 400;

            pic.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);   
        }
    }


    public String mili_t(int t)
    {
        int s = (int) (t / 1000) % 60 ;
        int m = (int) ((t / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int h = (int) ((t / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        String dt="", dh, ds, dm;

        if(h>0)
        {
            dh=Integer.toString(h);
            if(h<10) dh="0"+dh;
            dt=dt+dh+":";
        }
        if(m>=0)
        {
            dm=Integer.toString(m);
            if(m<10) dm="0"+dm;
            dt=dt+dm+":";
        }
        if(s>=0)
        {
            ds=Integer.toString(s);
            if(s<10) ds="0"+ds;
            dt=dt+ds;
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public void showTost(String s) 
    { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
        {
            tadapter.getFilter().filter(s);                               
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

}
```

And the xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popupwrap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bdcolor">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bdcolor">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/bbcolor"
        android:hint="SEARCH FILTER"
        android:background="@drawable/etext"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
        android:textColor="@color/gcolor"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"  
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_addtoplay"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/check1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>   

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:id="@+id/lst_traki2add">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out and modified the adapter. I replaced File with a custom object that has a boolean in it.

Answer (score 0):

reason is simple - you have `OnCheckedChangeListener` which fires after every (un)check and is changing background. Everytime you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` whole list will be redrawn, so background color will be again set with `if(position1 %2 == 1)` condition in `getView` method, but listener won't fire again. check out his code with manual listener call

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (cb_plus.isChecked())
            {
                cb_plus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x2);       
                txt.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bdcolor));

                rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.acolor);

                if(piosenki.get(album.get(position1)) != null) // won't duplicate
                    piosenki.add(album.get(position1));
            }
            else 
            {
                cb_plus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus);
                txt.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gcolor));

                if(position1 %2 == 1) rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bbcolor);
                else rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bpcolor);

                piosenki.remove(album.get(position1));
            }
        }
    }
boolean isAdded = ...;
cb_plus.setChecked(isAdded);

cb_plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener); // set listener after setting (un)checked
listener.onCheckedChanged(cb_plus, isAdded); // manual call
```

`isAdded` is your condition for `CheckBox` checked or not, problably `piosenki.contains(album.get(position1));` or `piosenki.get(album.get(position1)) != null;`. you can also get rid of few duplicated lines from `getView` method, like those with background or textcolor setting - these will be called inside manual listener call

PS. also change `piosenki` to `songs` ;)

Comment: think about upvoting/accepting answer(s) ;) powodzenia

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are relying on the `Checkbox` view in each row to maintain the selection state for that row. You will also see strange behavior if you have a long list of songs, select some, and then scroll. Both of these problems are because `ListView` will recycle the views that are used to render the songs that are currently displayed rather than creating a new set of views for every row.

To solve this problem, you need to maintain the selection state yourself. You can do this with a `bool[]` or `List<Boolean>` that stores a flag for every song in your current data. Use this to set the background color and checkbox state rather than relying on the checkbox state to set the background color.

Comment: Thank you, I replaced File with an object that has a bool it in.